# How to change or specify a DVC experiment name?

Tags: continuous-integration, mlops, dvc

How do I change the name of the experiment? I tried to use `dvc exp run -n` to name the project then use git to push to github. However the experiment name is still SHA.

[image]

Tried: I tried to use `dvc exp run -n` to name the project then use git to push to github. However the experiment name is still SHA.
Expected experiment name on iterative studio interface to display the name
Actually happened: Github SHA value instead of the name

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change the name after the experiment has been run however it can always be deleted and run again with `-n` as you mentioned. More info: https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/experiment-management#how-does-dvc-track-experiments

Comment: Are you making the experiment "persistent" with `dvc exp branch` or `dvc exp apply` before pushing them with Git? Because in that case they cease to be special DVC experiments (losing their name) and become regular Git commits (identified by SHA). See https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/experiment-management/persisting-experiments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of experiments in DVC ecosystem that we need to distinguish and there are a few different approaches on naming them.

First, is what we sometimes call "ephemeral" experiments, those that do not create commits in your Git history unless you explicitly say so. They are described in this [Get Started section](https://dvc.org/doc/start/experiment-management/experiments). For each of those experiments a name is auto-generated (e.g. `angry-upas` in one of the examples from the doc) or you could use `dvc exp run -n ...` to pass a particular name to it.

Another way to create those experiments (+ send them to Studio) is to use DVC logger (`DVCLive`), e.g. it's described [here](https://dvc.org/doc/studio/user-guide/projects-and-experiments/live-metrics-and-plots). Those experiments will be visible in Studio with an auto-generated names (or a name that was provided when they were created).

Now, we have another type of an experiment - a commit. Something that someone decided to make persistent and share with the team via PR and/or via a regular commit. Those are presented in the image that is shared in the Question.

Since they are regular commits, the regular Git rules apply to them - they have hash, they have descriptions, and most relevant to this discussion is that they have `tags`. All this information will be reflected in Studio UI.

E.g. in this public [example-get-started repo](https://studio.iterative.ai/user/shcheklein/projects/example-get-started-yj0q1nba3g?columns=lWz2cHgsZZMJxOksbrqRp):

[image]

It think in your case, `tags` would be the most natural way to rename those. May be we can introduce a way to push exp name as a git tag along with the experiment when it's being saved. WDYT?

Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply! I that will be helpful with versioning:)

Comment: I think tagging is only relatable if you want to make experiment persistent. But sometimes you want to better "label" experiments just for yourself too. e.g. I fastly iterated on code in 4 different ways and started dvc experiments, and then I look at experiment and think "what was that particular experiment about?".
Sometimes you want to "first create experiment; then name it", not wasting valuable iteration time on naming.